# Matching keyword from text file containing gmail imap dump Python 3, windows 8

Tags: python, word-wrap, gmail-imap, keyword-search

I have two scripts;
The first checks my email folder and writes what it gets to a text file:

```
def email_checker():
   import imaplib
   import textwrap

   mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
   mail.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
   mail.list()
   mail.select('inbox')

   typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
   my_file = open("email.txt", "w")

   for num in data[0].split():
      typ, newb = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')   
      print ('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, newb[0][1]))
      my_file.write('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, newb[0][1]))

      #my_out = textwrap.wrap(str(('Message %s\n %s\n' % (num, newb[0][1]))),70)
      #my_file.write(my_out)
   mail.close()
   my_file.close()
```

The second functions is then supposed to check this file to find a keyword.

```
def keyword_match (keyword):

   with open("email.txt", "r") as openfile:
       for line in openfile:
           for part in line.split():
               if part == keyword:
                   print ("working")
                   return True

               else:
                   return False
```

The problem is that the keyword matcher does not return True even when using words I know exist in the email.

I have tried to use textwrap (see commented out code) but it gives me an error TypeError: must be str, not list

I am using Python 3, on a windows 8, 64 bit machine.

Update:

- Ok so I created a new text file with "This is my test sentence" and then ran the keyword match on it for "test" and that works.
- The print to in email_checker seems to work fine and prints out lots of detail about the email and the contents which contain the keywords being searched for.
- The strings in the text file do seem to contain the contents so I don't think its a case of missing content in the txt file as I originally thought.
- Ok I think I have fixed it. My updated code looks like this and seems to work.

  def keyword_match (keyword):

  with open("email.txt", "r") as openfile:
      for line in openfile:
          for part in line.split():

  ```
          if part == keyword:
              print ("working")
              return True
              break

       else:
        return False
  ```

Final Update: Sorry I am trying to put the code in but it seems to have a mind of its own when it comes to what to accept as a code snippet. But essentially I put a break after the if and moved the else two steps out so as to make it a "for else loop"

Comment: does `if part.strip() == keyword` return True?

Comment: I think there is a serious mismatch between title and question here!

Comment: Does `print ('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, newb[0][1]))` show the right stuff?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist; I am fairly new to this. Do you have any title change suggestions?

Comment: @tdelaney; Thanks, yes the print seems to work correctly.

Comment: Ok I seem to have fixed it will update soon

Comment: @user4029 New title looks fine. The objection I had was to the part about data loss which is a vastly different problem than you were having. :)